Исправление вывода даты и времени в Django REST - убрать букву Т
В БД Postgres дата и время отображаются относительно нормально, примерно, так:
2024-05-27 14:34:50.000 +0400

А при выводе через бэкенд АПИ Django REST вывод такой:
2024-05-28T04:52:29

Как убрать букву "Т" между датой и временем?
Настройки я уже разные пробовал, но ничего не помогло.

А вам точно нужно отдавать именно дату-время? В запросе, ещё на стороне PostgreSQL, выполните явную конвертацию в TEXT, можно даже с требуемым форматом - тогда CMS никаких своих дурацких преобразований применять не будет. А потом, если оно надо не только для показать, но и для расчётов, несложно текстовый литерал известного формата конвертировать обратно в DATETIME.

@Akina То есть Вы предлагаете поле timestamptz преобразовать в varchar?

Нет, я просто предлагаю вместо SELECT ts, ... делать SELECT ts :: TEXT AS ts, ..

@Akina У меня Django REST (апи в бэкенде) отдаёт данные. Там нет прямого SELECT'а.

А я и не говорю о сыром SQL. Либо почитайте мануал - указанное преобразование должно иметь соотв. маппинг в рамках синтаксиса фреймворка,- либо создайте представление с требуемым преобразованием. Крайний вариант - виртуальное вычисляемое поле.
